# Routine to check if a given date is summertime or wintertime

Tags: c++, winapi, datetime

Do you know if an API exists for that checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724421(VS.85).aspx) is what you need.

You can call it and inspect the returned value to detect whether daylight saving is on at the moment of call. It also fills a structure that contains rules for switching to daylight saving and from daylight saving. Having this structure filled and any given time in UTC format you can relatively easily compute whether that time corrspongs to daylight saving time or standard time.

Comment: is there any linux equivalent ? Or better a lib that encapsulate it ? I will check boost ;)

Comment: Be careful, though, if you want to take historical changes to transition dates into account. E.g. the US and Australia have recently changed the dates for when they alter between daylight saving time and normal time, and a given timestamp from 2003 lives under different rules than a given timestamp from 2008.

Comment: Boost has Boost.Date_Time [1], containing a time zone database, among other things.

I haven't used it, so I can't vouch for its quality.

[1] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: @Kim: Yes, that true and that's a problem that can't be easily solved.

Comment: @sharptooth: Newer Windows versions (Vista+) has a couple of helper functions for this, and Microsoft try to keep the registry updated with legislative changes. See GetTimeZoneInformationForYear [1] and GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation [2]

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540851(VS.85).aspx
[2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724318(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

All well and good, but GetTimeZoneInformation and GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation only return the *current* time zone settings.  What if the current TZ (i.e., where my server lives) is not the TZ that I want to check?

Let's say that I have a server app that reserves books for checkout.  You can say "I want to check it out now" or "I'm going to need to check it out at *datetime* in the future".  Checkout times are entered in the user's local time and converted to UTC before storing.  When the user retrieves their list of checkouts the times are converted back to their local for display.

Assume that the server lives in New York and operates under standard post-2007 DST rules for the USA.  The timezone is set to Eastern US, and it's currently 7/27/2009 15:30, so DST is ON.

Users in New York enter local dates and times.  Convert from ET to UTC - not a problem.  They enter a future date - fine.  I use one of the above two API calls and figure it out.

However, a user in Sydney wants to reserve a checkout.  She requests a checkout on 12/13/2009 18:25 relative to her local timezone in Sydney.  I can't use my local TZ info - Sydney and NY don't follow the same DST rules.  How do I go about loading Sydney's current TZ information and finding out if an arbitrary date is DST or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are some newer (but still incomplete) methods available on MS-Windows for Win7 and Server2008/R2. See KB 2731771. Also see ICU and Boost::locale.
The Windows routines (GetTimeZoneInformationForYear) requires you have converted your UTC as far as getting the year at a minimum. Luckily, no time zones shift right around Jan 1 that I'm aware of. You can use SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(Ex) to get local time properly converted to a time zone that differs from the local system's time zone.
Without these methods you need to scan the registry to load the proper time zone information and dynamic information, then calling SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime.
Be careful using things like _tzset and localtime as some systems (like Windows) assume many (mostly incorrect) things like using US DST rules even if your TZ settings are for Australia.

You'd think that both Windows and Linux would have some pretty standard way of doing something like UTCtoLocal(const char *tzName, time_t inTime, struct tm *outTime) taking into account all dynamic/historical DST rules for the time zone given. tzName should be able to take the appropriate name like "Central Standard Time" or "America/Chicago" depending on what system you are running on. I'd even be willing to allow a two-call step like
  GetTimeZoneInformation(const char *tzName, TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION *outTZInfo)
  UTCtoLocal(const TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION *inTZInfo, time_t inTime, struct tm *outTime)
You know the OS is already doing this when it loads the system timezone information and the libraries do local/UTC conversions.